# How can I sort results on someone else's webpage?

Tags: html, sorting, web-crawler

I'd like to sort a list of results on someone else's webpage.

On this webpage each result item is being displayed with its popularity rate. I'd like to sort the results according to their popularity.

Unfortunately this webpage offers neither a sorting option for its users nor an API.

I was thinking of crawling all the pages, searching in the HTML code for the popularity rate and then sort it.

What do you suggests? What's the best strategy to go for?

Comment: What methods have you tried so far? Can you please show us some directed code that we can improve upon rather than simply asking for an opinion? Opinion questions are off-topic on Stack Overflow.

Comment: So far, I have nothing. I thought it'd be better to ask for a good theoretical solution first before coding...

Comment: Try PhantomJS. http://phantomjs.org

Answer (score 0):

If the list of results is presented as a table, if popularity is a column and you'll use your browser for it, then you can use the [sort table bookmarklet](https://www.squarefree.com/bookmarklets/pagedata.html) from Jesse Ruderman. It will add an extra column ("a/d") at the top of each column which you can use for sorting it in ascending or descending order.

You just need to drag and drop it to your bookmarks toolbar or create a bookmark with the corresponding JavaScript code (make sure there are no spaces):

```
javascript:function%20toArray%20(c){var%20a,%20k;a=new%20Array;for%20(k=0;%20k<c.length;%20++k)a[k]=c[k];return%20a;}function%20insAtTop(par,child){if(par.childNodes.length)%20par.insertBefore(child,%20par.childNodes[0]);else%20par.appendChild(child);}function%20countCols(tab){var%20nCols,%20i;nCols=0;for(i=0;i<tab.rows.length;++i)if(tab.rows[i].cells.length>nCols)nCols=tab.rows[i].cells.length;return%20nCols;}function%20makeHeaderLink(tableNo,%20colNo,%20ord){var%20link;link=document.createElement('a');link.href='javascript:sortTable('+tableNo+','+colNo+','+ord+');';link.appendChild(document.createTextNode((ord>0)?'a':'d'));return%20link;}function%20makeHeader(tableNo,nCols){var%20header,%20headerCell,%20i;header=document.createElement('tr');for(i=0;i<nCols;++i){headerCell=document.createElement('td');headerCell.appendChild(makeHeaderLink(tableNo,i,1));headerCell.appendChild(document.createTextNode('/'));headerCell.appendChild(makeHeaderLink(tableNo,i,-1));header.appendChild(headerCell);}return%20header;}g_tables=toArray(document.getElementsByTagName('table'));if(!g_tables.length)%20alert("This%20page%20doesn't%20contain%20any%20tables.");(function(){var%20j,%20thead;for(j=0;j<g_tables.length;++j){thead=g_tables[j].createTHead();insAtTop(thead,%20makeHeader(j,countCols(g_tables[j])))}})%20();function%20compareRows(a,b){if(a.sortKey==b.sortKey)return%200;return%20(a.sortKey%20<%20b.sortKey)%20?%20g_order%20:%20-g_order;}function%20sortTable(tableNo,%20colNo,%20ord){var%20table,%20rows,%20nR,%20bs,%20i,%20j,%20temp;g_order=ord;g_colNo=colNo;table=g_tables[tableNo];rows=new%20Array();nR=0;bs=table.tBodies;for(i=0;%20i<bs.length;%20++i)for(j=0;%20j<bs[i].rows.length;%20++j){rows[nR]=bs[i].rows[j];temp=rows[nR].cells[g_colNo];if(temp)%20rows[nR].sortKey=temp.innerHTML;else%20rows[nR].sortKey="";++nR;}rows.sort(compareRows);for%20(i=0;%20i%20<%20rows.length;%20++i)insAtTop(table.tBodies[0],%20rows[i]);}
```

If you're interested in what the code does, you can beautify it using an online JavaScript beautifier. This is what you get:

```
javascript: function toArray(c) {
    var a, k;
    a = new Array;
    for (k = 0; k < c.length; ++k) a[k] = c[k];
    return a;
}

function insAtTop(par, child) {
    if (par.childNodes.length) par.insertBefore(child, par.childNodes[0]);
    else par.appendChild(child);
}

function countCols(tab) {
    var nCols, i;
    nCols = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < tab.rows.length; ++i)
        if (tab.rows[i].cells.length > nCols) nCols = tab.rows[i].cells.length;
    return nCols;
}

function makeHeaderLink(tableNo, colNo, ord) {
    var link;
    link = document.createElement('a');
    link.href = 'javascript:sortTable(' + tableNo + ',' + colNo + ',' + ord + ');';
    link.appendChild(document.createTextNode((ord > 0) ? 'a' : 'd'));
    return link;
}

function makeHeader(tableNo, nCols) {
    var header, headerCell, i;
    header = document.createElement('tr');
    for (i = 0; i < nCols; ++i) {
        headerCell = document.createElement('td');
        headerCell.appendChild(makeHeaderLink(tableNo, i, 1));
        headerCell.appendChild(document.createTextNode('/'));
        headerCell.appendChild(makeHeaderLink(tableNo, i, -1));
        header.appendChild(headerCell);
    }
    return header;
}
g_tables = toArray(document.getElementsByTagName('table'));
if (!g_tables.length) alert("This page doesn't contain any tables.");
(function() {
    var j, thead;
    for (j = 0; j < g_tables.length; ++j) {
        thead = g_tables[j].createTHead();
        insAtTop(thead, makeHeader(j, countCols(g_tables[j])))
    }
})();

function compareRows(a, b) {
    if (a.sortKey == b.sortKey) return 0;
    return (a.sortKey < b.sortKey) ? g_order : -g_order;
}

function sortTable(tableNo, colNo, ord) {
    var table, rows, nR, bs, i, j, temp;
    g_order = ord;
    g_colNo = colNo;
    table = g_tables[tableNo];
    rows = new Array();
    nR = 0;
    bs = table.tBodies;
    for (i = 0; i < bs.length; ++i)
        for (j = 0; j < bs[i].rows.length; ++j) {
            rows[nR] = bs[i].rows[j];
            temp = rows[nR].cells[g_colNo];
            if (temp) rows[nR].sortKey = temp.innerHTML;
            else rows[nR].sortKey = "";
            ++nR;
        }
    rows.sort(compareRows);
    for (i = 0; i < rows.length; ++i) insAtTop(table.tBodies[0], rows[i]);
}
```